# How to use HandbrakeCLI GPU encoding?

Tags: handbrake

I tried

```
HandBrakeCLI -i file1.mkv -o output.mp4 -e nvenc_h264 --encopts="gpu=1"
```

where `gpu=1` means my nVidia 3070. It'd stop about 2 seconds after it prints:

```
03:11:13 encavcodecInit: H.265 (Nvidia NVENC)
Encoding: task 1 of 1, 0.00%
```

I tried removing

```
--encopts="gpu=1"
```

and it didn't work.  I tried changing to `0` and it didn't work. I also tried

```
--encopts="gpu=1;coder=auto"
```

in [the docs here](https://handbrake.fr/docs/en/latest/technical/video-nvenc.html) and it didn't work. I also tried `gpu=any` and it didn't work.

Can it be made to work at all? I saw [an article saying it is about 5 times as fast as using the CPU to encode](https://www.ryananddebi.com/2020/06/26/handbrake-convert-files-with-gpu-nvenc-rather-than-cpu/).

Comment: What is your end goal here? If it just is switching the format (container), and you don't really want to change the video, you could easily use ffmpeg instead. If you want to transcode the video to be visually lossless with a smaller file size, you should try [Other Video Transcoding](https://github.com/donmelton/other_video_transcoding) by Don Melton, it does a great job at that as it is made to "compress" ripped BluRays

Answer (score 1):

`HandBrakeCLI -i in.mkv -o out.mkv -e nvenc_h265`

tried all your steps without result.

adding `-e nvenc_h265` worked for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: so the only thing different is that you use `-e nvenc_h265` instead of my `-e nvenc_h264`?  I need to double check to confirm it is working